# Java, MySql -- connecting from another computer

Tags: java, mysql

I created a java program that uses MySql. Now I want to give the app to someone else, and I'm using the URL as: `jdbc:mysql://ipAddress:3306/tableName`, but it doesn't work, showing the error of connection failure.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a troubleshooting stuff, do the following.

1. Check the Firewall and Port access on MySQL Server computer.
2. Check the MySQL Service and the DB User is doing good.
3. Follow the following thread

> [How to allow remote connection to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779104/how-to-allow-remote-connection-to-mysql)